# How to get values from button in Rasa?

Tags: python, rasa-core

I want to get access to the payload values from my custom buttons. The main idea is to choose one option from the buttons, and then collect the payload values in a variable, in order to pass these to the next action.

The custom buttons are in a loop where from each items I collect the needed values for the “titles” and for the “payloads”. I want to achieve this in a dynamic way, since I have a lot of different variables with different length.

Here is my code until now:

```
def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
         tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any],
     ) -> Text:
   for element in request.question.items:
   for l in element['choices']:
   buttons.append({"title": "{}".format(l['label']), "payload": "{}{}".format(element['id'],l['id'])})

   return [] 
dispatcher.utter_button_message(message, buttons)
```

Again, my question is how to access the selected payload values. In rasa x I can see that the payload is being selected properly, for example: "11,true".

But I find no way to get these values into another variable.
I also tried `tracker.latest_message.get(‘text’)`, but I only get the last user input.

Is there a similar function to "tracker.latest_message.get" for the last chosen button option or last utterance from bot?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried /<intent>{entity} in your payload. and you have to map that entity to a slot, then you can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a button payload like `/intent_name{"slot_name": "value"}` then you can directly trigger a certain intent (e.g. `intent_name`) and pass a slot / entity (e.g. `slot_name`) with a value (e.g. `value`) to Rasa Core. In this case you don't even need a custom action to extract the values since these are automatically extracted by Rasa (Core). Otherwise you'd find these values in the slots / entities of a conversation.

> But I find no way to get these values into another variable. I also tried tracker.latest_message.get(‘text’), but I only get the last user input.

Is the last user input not the payload of the button the user pressed?

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for your answer. I get your idea, bot the problem is I don't want to use slots in the payload since these are dynamically set from an API, thats why I use:
 buttons.append({"title": "{}".format(l['label']), "payload": "{}{}".format(element['id'],l['id'])}). I don't really know what the value would be, it is always different. If using slots I will have to generate data in NLU in order to recognize the intent, right?

Comment: tracker.latest_message.get(‘text’) returns the last typed user input, not the payload. May be there is a method how to collect the information from the pay load, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Did you find the solution of how to get the clicked-button as a text? @El_Patrón